# Extract all the email ids from the list of objects using streams, flatmaps

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the below structure. I want to get the output as a list of all the email ids extracted from all the Parent objects. The output I'm looking for is: Aaron@gmail.com, tom@gmail.com, jerry@gmail.com, Tim@gmail.com, ryan@gmail.com, sean@gmail.com

I want to achieve this using streams/flatmaps. Is it possible to achieve this purely using streams/flatmaps/maps?

```
    public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String ar[]) {
            List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
            Parent p1 = new Parent();
            p1.setEmail(new Metadata("Aaron@gmail.com"));
            Parent p2 = new Parent();
            p2.setEmail(new Metadata("Tim@gmail.com"));
    
            List<String> emailIds1 = new ArrayList<>();
            emailIds1.add("tom@gmail.com");
            emailIds1.add("jerry@gmail.com");
            p1.setEmails(emailIds1);
    
            List<String> emailIds2 = new ArrayList<>();
            emailIds2.add("ryan@gmail.com");
            emailIds2.add("sean@gmail.com");
            p2.setEmails(emailIds2);
    
            parents.add(p1);
            parents.add(p2);
    
            /*
            *  Ierate through 'parents' and get all the email ids. The output of the above should be as below:
            *
            * o/p: Aaron@gmail.com, tom@gmail.com, jerry@gmail.com, Tim@gmail.com, ryan@gmail.com, sean@gmail.com
             * */
            List<String> flatenned = parents.stream()
                    .flatMap() //
        }
    }
    // The class that contains all the data
    class Parent {
        Metadata email;
        List<String> emails;
    
        public void setEmails(List<String> emails) {
            this.emails = emails;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(Metadata email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }



----------

//Metadata class which container extra email addresses
    class Metadata {
        String email;
    
        public Metadata(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }`enter code here`
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` to get flatten the list of emails and concat with single email and then collect.

```
List<String> flatenned = parents.stream()
                                .flatMap(p -> Stream.concat(p.getEmails().stream(), 
                                                 Stream.of(p.getEmail().getEmail())))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Update :
You can use Optional for returning empty list when list is null

```
List<String> flatenned = Optional.ofNullable(parents)
        .map(m -> m.stream()
            .flatMap(p -> Stream.concat(p.getEmails().stream(),
                             Stream.of(p.getEmail().getEmail())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: The above code would return '[tom@gmail.com, jerry@gmail.com, ryan@gmail.com, sean@gmail.com]', but I need 'Aaron@gmail.com, tom@gmail.com, jerry@gmail.com, Tim@gmail.com, ryan@gmail.com, sean@gmail.com'

Comment: Try now updated

Comment: that worked. Also, is it possible to do a null check on 'parents' before we perform the flatmap operation? If so, how do we do it? Essentially, we should return back an empty list if 'parents' is null

Comment: Check if parrents is not null then do the operation else return `Collections.emptyList()`

Comment: An example added using Optional